# How to fix appbar while navigating through pages in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to navigate through screens but I need to change only the content of the body and the appbar stays as it is. I am having 4 files namely main.dart, screen1.dart, screen2.dart, and globals.dart. Screen1 is having a button to goto Screen2 and vice versa. When I clicked the button in screen1 it need to navigate to screen 2 and vice versa, but when I clicked the button nothing is happening. Here is my code:

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:demo/globals.dart';
import 'package:demo/screen2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyApp(),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    buildBody = Screen1();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepOrange,
        title: Text('Fixed AppBar'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: buildBody,
    );
  }
}
```

**screen1.dart**

```
import 'package:demo/screen2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Screen1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Screen1State createState() => _Screen1State();
}

class _Screen1State extends State<Screen1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.green,
      child: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text('Goto Screen 2', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              buildBody = Screen2();
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**screen2.dart**

```
import 'package:demo/screen1.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Screen2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Screen2State createState() => _Screen2State();
}

class _Screen2State extends State<Screen2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.brown,
      child: Center(
        child: FlatButton(
          child: Text(
            'Goto Screen 1',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              buildBody = Screen1();
            });
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**globals.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Widget buildBody;
```

Comment: Share your globals.dart file. I would prefer separating the files, each with its own appbar but with similar implementation. The main file should then define all the app routes.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Scaffold in main file after MaterialApp
,  use it in every separated screen use you custom content and the title you want.

Answer (score 0):

Check out PageView https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PageView-class.html
From flutter docs. I think that will work or use Tabs